# Excluding unnecessary files from deployment

Tags: javascript, deployment, bower

I have started to learn how to use RequireJS and the Bower package management system. I define the `bower.json` file like this:

```
  {

    "name": "App",
    "version": "1.0",
    "dependencies": {

        "jquery": null,
        "backbone-amd": null,
        "underscore-amd": null,
        "requirejs": null,
        "handlebars": null,
        "mustache" : null

    }

}
```

It downloads libraries but also downloads example files and docs for `backbone-amd`, `underscore-amd`, and `requirejs`. The size of my project then is 52 MB (and after building with `r.js`, 42 MB). Is there a way to exclude the unnecessary files and reduce project's size (except by removing and deleting it manually)?

Comment: Unclear. 1) If this is a git problem (as evidenced by the currently accepted answer), why is git mentioned nowhere in the question? 2) The question as currently framed (concern about the size of ``r.js``' output) makes it sound like an issue with what is passed to the browser.

Comment: Sorry, I tought that this is solution, problem is when I localy run bower install it downloads all files but also downloads docs and examples. After build that files are present also and that incrises project size. Is there a way to download only librarys eg. requirejs.js without examples and docs. My english is not so good :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a building tool like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) to avoid having to do it manually over and over again. Here's what I do. My projects are often structured like this:

- `lib/` Contains the project's own code.
- `build/` Contains result of building the project. In other words, the code that should be installed on a server.

Then I have a build setup using Grunt or make that uses the code in `lib/` plus vendor packages downloaded through Bower, npm or some other means to create the files under `build/`.

The build typically uses either of the following methods to deal with vendor packages:

1. If the package does not contain unnecessary files (like examples and documentation), just copy it to an appropriate place in `build/`.

   This method is preferable. To determine whether it is possible to use this method, you have to check how the vendor has packaged their software. Some libraries are distributed in multiple packages. [Lodash](http://lodash.com/), for instance, has 170 packages available through npm. So for a library that has multiple packages available, you should check whether there is one that does not contain the unnecessary information. If this is the case, this method can be used.
2. If the package does contain unnecessary files, then the build process needs to be a bit more intelligent and copy *only* the files needed.

   Sooner or later, you will run into a situation where some software you want to use is distributed with files you do not want. This is *guaranteed* to happen.

   In this case, you could communicate with the developers and point out how nice it would be if they could package their software so that it contains only the files necessary for deployment. If they accept to add a package for their software that contains only necessary files, then you can use the first method above.

   Otherwise, you have to learn how the software is structured, determine what you absolutely need, and write a function for your build process (Grunt, make, or something else) that copies over only the files you need.

Answer (score 3):

The common workflow is that you put your bower verdor directory in `.gitignore` and then you will run bower again after you deploy your code on the server. And that is the purpose of any dependency management library

Comment: yeah best answer ever, :D